# Excel VBA Replace using String to Find and Array Value to Replace

Tags: excel, vba, replace

Just looking for some assistance with the following block of code. What I am trying to do here is replace static variables contained within a letter with their corresponding value.

The code is meant to loop through a table and for each row under the column [Variable] replaces any instance of that variable with that found in 'blankLetter'. Maybe this isn't the best way to achieve this...

```
Public Function letterReplace(blankLetter As String, letterArray As Dictionary) As String
'Lookup the variable table and for each variable replace the instance of that in the array
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim row As Range
Dim temp As String
For Each row In [varTable[Variable]].Rows
    'temp = "<PURVNAME>"
    temp = row.Value
    letterReplace = Replace(blankLetter, temp, letterArray(temp))
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

The following works fine:

```
letterReplace = Replace(blankLetter, "<PURVNAME>", letterArray("<PURVNAME>"))
```

However this line does not replace anything:

```
letterReplace = Replace(blankLetter, temp, letterArray(temp))
```

Ive had a search but coming up trumps.

Any help would be great.

Mark

Comment: You'd better show some examples of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time through the loop you do a single replace on the original `blankLetter` argument and place the result in `letterReplace`: only the last of those replace operations will make it out of the function as the return value.

You need to keep executing the Replace operations on the same variable.

```
Public Function letterReplace(blankLetter As String, letterArray As Dictionary) As String
'Lookup the variable table and for each variable replace the 
'   instance of that in the array

    Dim row As Range, retVal As String
    Dim temp As String

    retVal = blankLetter
    For Each row In [varTable[Variable]].Rows
        temp = row.Value
        retVal  = Replace(retVal, temp, letterArray(temp))
    Next

    letterReplace = retVal
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim Williams, works perfectly and makes sense.  Cheers.